# ggplot2: Mixing of labels and colours using scale_colour_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a scatterplot where I want 4 guide lines. I have not used variables from the dataset directly to defines those lines in the plot script. (The vertical lines is mean and median of the x-values. And the slopes of the two other lines are 1 and 0.5.)
How can I define colours for the lines and get correct legend labels? In my plot the colours and labels are mixed up.

The question answered [here (possibly duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063163/how-to-add-manual-colors-for-a-ggplot2-geom-smooth-geom-line) is similar to my question above, but not completely, I think. The former question is about difference between scale_colour - and scale_fill_manual and the importance to include aes() to get a legend, I think. My question is about mixing of legend-labels and colours since I had not defined the values in the geom_- call and had separated the values and colours in the scale_colour_manual().

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do({
    mod = lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length, data = .)
    data.frame(Intercept = coef(mod)[1],
               Slope = coef(mod)[2],
               SD= summary(mod)$coefficients[2,2])
  })

meanSlope <- mean(df$Slope)
medianSlope <- median(df$Slope)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Slope, y=SD)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1.0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1.0))+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 1, colour="red"), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 0.5, colour="blue"), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = meanSlope, colour= "green"), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept= medianSlope, colour= "darkgreen"), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Guide lines", values=c("red", "blue", "green", "darkgreen"), 
                      labels=c("1 SD", "0.5 SD", "mean", "median"))
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063163/how-to-add-manual-colors-for-a-ggplot2-geom-smooth-geom-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add manual colors for a ggplot2 (geom\_smooth/geom\_line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063163/how-to-add-manual-colors-for-a-ggplot2-geom-smooth-geom-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mapping to the name of the line, then setting colors afterwards:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Slope, y=SD)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.0))+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 1, colour = "1 SD"), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 0.5, colour = "0.5 SD"), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = meanSlope, colour = "mean"), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept= medianSlope, colour = "median"), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Guide lines", 
                      values = c('1 SD' = "red", '0.5 SD' = "blue", 
                                 mean = "green", median = "darkgreen"))
```

[image]